# Proof that $x_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and $x_n\gt 0$ $\implies$ $\{x_n\}$ has a max

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $x_n \gt 0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = 0$.  Show that the set $$S = \{x_n \mid n\in \Bbb N\}$$ contains a maximum member.

Here's the argument I wanted to make:

---

Since $x_n$ converges to $0$ then there exists $N, M\in \Bbb N$ such that

1. $N\le M$,
2. $|x_n| \le 1$ for all $n\ge N$, and
3. $|x_n| \le \frac 12$ for all $n\ge M$.

The sets $\{x_n\}_{n \in [1,N-1]}$ and $\{x_n\}_{n \in [N,M]}$ are both finite sets and thus must contain maxima.  Call them $B_1$ and $B_2$ respectively.  Thus the maximum for $\{x_n\}$ will just be $\max(B_1, B_2)$.

---

However I noticed this won't necessarily work because the sequence might be all less than $\frac 12$ but increase for a bit and then start decreasing.  Then you could choose $N$ and $M$ such that the sequence doesn't hit its max until after $x_M$.  But I'd have the same problem for any two numbers I chose.  Maybe this is the wrong idea to prove this.

Comment: If instead of $x_n \leqslant 1$ you take $x_n \leqslant x_0$ as a condition?

Comment: Oh.  That's a good idea.  Thanks!

Comment: You can certainly patch up your argument with Daniel's suggestion.  It might also be worthwhile to see if you can make the argument with only one of $N,M$.  That is, say "there is some $N\in\mathbf{N}$ such that..."  It won't make your proof more correct, but a little cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the format of a delta-epsilon proof, since $x_n$ converges to 0, given an $\epsilon > 0$, we have an $N$ such that

$$|x_n|<\epsilon$$

for all $n \ge N$. Choose $\epsilon = x_1$ and we see that all numbers at the tail end of the sequence are smaller than $x_1$. Then the maximum of set $S$ would be $\max\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n-1}\}$, which is a finite set (therefore the maximum exists). Therefore, set $S$ has a maximum element.